# what is different at httpService.get and httpService.axiosRef.get @nestjs/axios?

Tags: axios, rxjs, nestjs

I'm new to nestJS and RxJS and try to use axios for http request.

I noticed there're two options when using axios API.

1. using HttpService.get. it returns Observable and RxJS should be used together.
2. using HttpService.axiosRef.get. it returns Promise.

What is diff between 2 options??

ex) performance, catching error. etc.....

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpService#get` is the observable wrapped axios call. `HttpService#axiosRef.get` is the raw `axios.get` method, no observables added, just promises.

You can use either, just depends on your preference. You can also turn observables into a promise via `lastValueFrom(observable)` or a promise into an observable using `from(promise)`